# Series of novels involving aliens dragging a wormhole by the Earth, and a virus that makes blonde women want to breed

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

Things I remember:

- Aliens drag a wormhole right by Earth.
- One species releases a virus which makes 95% of blonde women into people who only want to breed.
- Humans buy an AI which controls mirrors in space to reflect sunlight as a weapon.
- Humans inflate a massive iron asteroid into huge space fortress.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall any details of the art?

Comment: @DavidW - within the past 10ish years, though it could've been written in the previous 10 years. I don't remember the art because I've been 100% ebook for years.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the *[Troy Rising](https://www.goodreads.com/series/51166-troy-rising)* series by John Ringo.

- Book 1: *[Live Free or Die](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17906325-live-free-or-die)* (2010)
- Book 2: *[Citadel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8157267-citadel)* (2011)
- Book 3: *[The Hot Gate](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8866354-the-hot-gate)* (2011)

The Goodreads synopsis of the first book mentions aliens dragging a gate to other worlds into the solar system:

> *First Contact Was Friendly*
>
> **When aliens trundled a gate to other worlds into the solar system, the world reacted with awe, hope and fear.** But the first aliens to come through, the Glatun, were peaceful traders and the world breathed a sigh of relief.
>
> *Who Controls the Orbitals, Controls the World*
>
> When the Horvath came through, they announced their ownership by dropping rocks on three cities and gutting them. Since then, they've held Terra as their own personal fiefdom. With their control of the orbitals, there's no way to win and earth's governments have accepted the status quo.
>
> *Live Free or Die.*
>
> To free the world from the grip of the Horvath is going to take an unlikely hero. A hero unwilling to back down to alien or human governments, unwilling to live in slavery and enough hubris, if not stature, to think he can win.
>
> Fortunately, there's Tyler Vernon. And he has bigger plans than just getting rid of Horvath.
>
> *Troy Rising* is a book in three parts-Live Free of Die being first part-detailing the freeing of earth from alien conquerors, the first steps into space using off-world technologies and the creation of Troy, a thousand trillion ton battlestation designed to secure the solar system.

And [this review](http://www.fantasyliterature.com/reviews/live-free-or-die/) of the first book mentions aliens releasing a virus that makes blonde women go into heat:

> It’s ironic that Tyler complains that liberals see him as rich and powerful and assume he’s greedy and domineering because… they’re right, he is. He expects the government to kowtow to him. When he decides to go messing around with mirrors in space and starts melting asteroids, it’s hard to believe that the world’s leaders would let him get away with that just because he’s rich. **All of this disgusted me, but when the aliens send a virus that makes blonde women go into heat, I dismissed the whole thing as John Ringo’s ugly wish fulfillment fantasy.** (And all women are appraised by whether or not they’re “stacked.”)

Comment: Yes, exactly this! Thank you.

Comment: I've never read John Ringo and yet somehow when I read the title of this question I knew it was going to be John Ringo.